# Swift - What is the meaning of this code hint?

Tags: swift

I have this type hinting in Swift and I don't understand the meaning:

```
FLSwiftUtils.getType(<#var: CMutablePointer<COpaquePointer>#>)
```

FLSwiftUtils is an Objc class, and getType a method.

What I don't understand is the semantical meaning of the type-hinting:

```
`<#var: CMutablePointer<COpaquePointer>#>`
```

(<# #> are placeholder for xcode to "highlight" the hinting, so you can copy-paste it)

This function expects a CMutablePointer, and this is ok, I know what is it, but what about the  inside the brackets?
As I understand, inside angle brackets you can have a **generic type** or a **protocol**, but COpaquePointer is not a generic type nor a protocol, it's a struct.

So, what is the meaning of CMutablePointer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CMutablePointer` is a generic type, `COpaquePointer` is what is inside. This is a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: Thanks, I was confusing the syntax